# Original creative ways representing users photo thumbnails on a social media homepage? and examples

Tags: visualization, concept-art

**What are creative ways of representing user profile pictures on a homepage ( or you can call them avatars but they will always be a real small version of a real photo  like 80x80 pixels in size. Are there any social networks that represent there users in a cool unique way? If you know some please share a link or an image :) thx!

you have,

- a social media type site
- users registered with profile photo
- enough photos to show on the homepage
- perhaps roulate them a bit

you want:

- creative way to represent those pictures
- be orginal use some colors and interaction ( rotate images)

Some examples I like and look for concepts like this ( Im not from India ):
[image]

Comment: i would look to other areas for inspiration other than other social networking sites maybe try some template websites i have this for example [link](http://www.templatemonster.com/website-templates/40497.html)

Answer (score 1):

What is imho a really neat concept, in terms of the way they represent things on their main, homepage, is [Pinterest](http://pinterest.com/).

This is not the users picture, but each users most recent photo or picture. They have width restrictions, but the height can be, well, very long. Which makes for a neat, refreshing interface at times.

When you have a uniform size of a picture, it makes it more difficult to be creative. so if you are going to keep your 80x80 standard size, indeed maybe an algorithm to randomly rotate them within a certain range. Use of color in frames or the background can be dangerous, for you will not know the color of the users picture or avatar.

If they are always a real picture - perhaps the use of numerous and various and creative frames would be interesting. That could work.